# Поиск по бд Firebase

Tags: java, android, база-данных, запрос, firebase

Есть `ListView` с множественным выбором,в 1 элемент которого входит к примеру - ингридиент для рецептов. Как мне реализовать поиск по моей бд в firebase нужных рецептов по выбранным элементам?  В одном из примеров на JavaScript видел использование `rootRef.child("users").orderByChild("email")` которая применялась к такой структуре данныъ в бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в Java я не нашел альтернативы. 
Структура моей бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно создать запрос в слушателе? Стоит ли мне как либо переработать структуру бд?

Comment: поиск по выбранным элементам - это значит поиск по значениям ключей id/имя/ингридиенты и тп?

Comment: @Maxgmer да по значениям `ингридиенты`

Comment: вот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537369/how-to-search-for-a-value-in-firebase-android, могу перевести ответом тут, если надо

Comment: @Maxgmer почитал. сделал вот так: `myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Рецепты");
        Query query_search = myRef.orderByChild("Ингридиенты").equalTo("Морковь");
        query_search.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                text.setText(value);` Но в итоге ничего не получил, что я сделал не так?

Comment: equalTo ищет строку, полностью равную строке "Морковь", у вас, как я понял, все ингредиенты хранятся в одной строке, поэтому не находит. "Морковь" не equalTo "Морковь, сахар, редис"

Comment: я не знаю как работает orderByChild, если он ищет по всем детям, а так же по детям детей, то можете изменить класс "Рецепты" так, чтобы Ингредиенты были массивом строк, а не строкой. Тогда будет работать, если orderByChild смотрит всю иерархию, ниже указанной

Comment: @Maxgmer так, переделал `.equalTo("Морковь, сахар, редис")` , получаю Массив значений, насколько я догадываюсь то я получаю полностью весь `child` 1. Как мне обрезать получаемое значение только до поля `Имя`?

Comment: String name = dataSnapshot.child("Имя").getValue();

Comment: @Maxgmer Чего то я затупил. Спасибо

Comment: @Maxgmer Странно... Но я не получаю никакого текста...         `myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Рецепты");
        Query query_search = myRef.orderByChild("Имя").equalTo("Морковный салат");
        query_search.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              
                String value_name = dataSnapshot.child("Имя").getValue(String.class);
                text.setText(value_name);`

Comment: Значит наверное оно сразу дает нужное и не нужно спускаться ниже по иерархии, чтобы проверять dataSnaphot, можно использовать метод hasChild(String path), чтобы проверить, есть ли такой путь ниже по иерархии, и exists(), чтобы проверить, есть ли вообще данные по вашему поиску.

Comment: @Maxgmer Если я не спускаюсь вниз то есть не использую эту конструкцию `String value_name = dataSnapshot.child("Имя").getValue(String.class);` Я получаю коллекцию значений, но мне нужно получить лишь Поле `Имя`

Comment: значит должен работать ваш вариант, который вы написали в комментариях, попробуйте создать вопрос, почему не работает вариант выше, а этот можете удалить